# Unable to start Bluetooth in le only mode (Linux poky)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, archlinux

I am trying to start Bluetooth in LE only mode when the system boots. I changed the "ControllerMode" to "le" in the main.conf file, I had to create the main.conf file because it wasn't there but that still did not work. Is there any other way that I can get bluetooth to start in LE only mode? Is there a way to force the configuration of bluetooth to not be reset upon reboot?

Note that in my distro I don't have bluez, I only have hci and btmgmt that I can work with

Thank you in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As `btmgmt` is part of the Bluez protocol stack your comment sound a little bit weird. Does "in my distro I don't have bluez" perhaps mean that you are not running the `bluetoothd` service? Then is the question which Bluetooth stack you use? You need to be much more specific about what hardware you are using, what software components and what you want to achieve. Otherwise I'm afraid you won't get a useful answer.

Comment: How do you know that your device is not working in LE only mode? What did you do to test this?